# Bootstrap Carousel transitions item + animate.css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, animate.css

I'm trying to animate `Bootstrap Carousel` with `animate.css`
I `finished with caption animation` everything works, but how to animate an `item`
HTML:

```
<div class="item zoomInLeft animated">
    <img data-src="/images/1.jpg" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h1 data-animation="bounceInDown" data-delay="400">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
       <h3 data-animation="bounceInDown" data-delay="600">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code for captions if anybody needs (JS)

```
function carousel_init(c){
        var self = this;
        self.carouselAnimations = function (elems) {
            elems.each(function (index) {
                var el = $(this);
                var animEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
                var animation = el.data('animation')+' animated';
                var delay = el.data('delay');
                el.attr('style', '-webkit-animation-delay:'+delay+'ms; -moz-animation-delay:'+delay+'ms; -o-animation-delay:'+delay+'ms; animation-delay:'+delay+'ms')
               .promise().done(function(){
                    el.addClass(animation).one(animEnd, function () {
                        el.removeClass(animation);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        var carousel = $(c);
        var firstElems = carousel.find('.item:first').find('[data-animation]'); 
        carousel.carousel({
            interval: 4000,
            pause:false,
            wrap:true
        });
        self.carouselAnimations(carousel, firstElems);
        carousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
            var elems = $(e.relatedTarget).find('[data-animation]'); 
            self.carouselAnimations(elems);
        });
    }
```

So I am goin throu all elements in `active.item` with `data-animation` (plus data-delay) and animating them.

> 1. It is possible also to `animate an Item` of bootstrap carousel?

if I just add class `zoomOutLeft animated` works but before that I need to add `zoomInLeft animated` (for example)
Thank you in adnvace

**Updated Question:**
@makshh Suggestion

```
.home-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  }
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner> .item.next,
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner> .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) scale(0.5) rotate(8deg);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) scale(0.5) rotate(8deg);
  }
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner> .item.prev,
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner> .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) scale(0.5) rotate(-8deg);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) scale(0.5) rotate(-8deg);
  }
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner> .item.next.left,
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner> .item.prev.right,
  .home-carousel .carousel-inner> .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1) rotate(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1) rotate(0);
  }
}
```

works but only in Chrome it is possible to make it work cross-browser becuase as I know transform3d works even in IE10+

**Update:** Removing `@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d)` makes it work in IE10+ (FF, Opera)

**But the question is still here can we integrate animate.css + bootstrap carousel.**

Comment: What exact animation do you need?

Comment: @makshh anything that is on animate.css

Comment: Maybe this will help you, I'm using transforms instead of animations http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/KzPOWb You can tweak with scale, rotate, skew etc.

Comment: @makshh Works only in Chrome

Comment: My solution with transforms?

Comment: @makshh Yes transforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML (nothing special, pure Bootstrap):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fa/No._23_Post_(Skelmorlie)_Image_3.jpg/640px-No._23_Post_(Skelmorlie)_Image_3.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Image-Lomnicky_stit_from_Slavkovsky_stit_2.jpg/640px-Image-Lomnicky_stit_from_Slavkovsky_stit_2.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Image-Peacock_Springs_Entrance.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Image-of-Sumadija-2.jpg/640px-Image-of-Sumadija-2.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Image-Great_Swamp_National_Wildlife_Refuge_New_Jersey03.jpg/640px-Image-Great_Swamp_National_Wildlife_Refuge_New_Jersey03.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (disabled transitions, transforms, and set left to 0, I also changed animation-duration to match Bootstrap carousel default duration, if you want different value than 0.6s you have to overwrite `Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600` in `bootstrap.js` file and change `animation-duration` to yours):

```
.item {
  transition: none !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
.animated {
  animation-duration: .6s;
}
```

JS (I didn't test it and I'm pretty sure it can be improved significantly):

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  if ($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.carousel-inner .item:first').addClass('animated zoomInDown');
  } else {
    $('.item.active').next().addClass('animated zoomInDown');
  }
  $('.item.active').addClass('animated zoomOutDown');
});

$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  $('.item').removeClass('animated zoomInDown zoomOutDown')
});

$('.left').click(function () {
  if ($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.carousel-inner .item:last').addClass('animated zoomInDown');
  } else {
    $('.item.active').prev().addClass('animated zoomInDown');
  }
});

$('.carousel-indicators > li').click(function () {
  $('.item').addClass('animated zoomInDown');
});
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/ONPmrG)**

Comment: If you worry about Firefox, I think there is nothing you can do. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=962594#c25